# Receive IR signals through camera

Tags: applications, camera, networking, remote-control

I want to receive IR signals on my phone. The camera can see IR, but I cannot tell which button I pressed. (yes, I know that's not how it works).

No app on the Play Store could help me because they all want to send IR signals. I tried to install LIRC through Termux, but it did not work.

After I receive the signal, I want to send it through a network socket.

Information:

- Model: Motorola Moto C
- Unrooted
- Android 7.0
- No extra bells and whistles

Comment: Yes CCD camera sensors can detect IR signals, but I am not sure if they can be used to read RC IR signals. Remote control IR signals usually have a frequency of 30-60Khz, most are at 38KHz. If I remember correctly for reading an analogue signal you need at minimum a measure frequency twice of the carrier signal, so you would need a measure frequency of 76KHz - which is a value I don't think that is technically possible with a CCD sensor eben if you only measure a small region of the chip. But you may want to ask the people at https://electronics.stackexchange.com if my assumptions are correct

Answer (score 0):

You need external IR recievier hardware to be able to reliable read IR signals (I guess you use TV remote or similar). Phone's camera is not meant to read signal (it's able to receive it, but not to read the message).